# consume json with array of objects in retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, object, retrofit2

I have this json I want to consume using the retrofit only that is not working very well

```
{
"point_period_data": [
    [
        {
            "sys_point_id": "60",
            "sys_point_registration": "12345678",
            "sys_point_day": "21",
            "sys_point_month": "12",
            "sys_point_year": "18",
            "sys_point_hour": "08",
            "sys_point_minute": "05",
            "sys_point_geo_lat": "-5.0787026",
            "sys_point_geo_long": "-42.8044331",
            "sys_point_status": "Falta",
            "sys_point_reference_code": "dc4e6ff10a"
        },
        {
            "sys_point_id": "61",
            "sys_point_registration": "12345678",
            "sys_point_day": "21",
            "sys_point_month": "12",
            "sys_point_year": "18",
            "sys_point_hour": "17",
            "sys_point_minute": "28",
            "sys_point_geo_lat": "-5.0787569",
            "sys_point_geo_long": "-42.804378",
            "sys_point_status": "Falta",
            "sys_point_reference_code": "b11a829fda"
        },
        {
            "sys_point_id": "62",
            "sys_point_registration": "12345678",
            "sys_point_day": "21",
            "sys_point_month": "12",
            "sys_point_year": "18",
            "sys_point_hour": "17",
            "sys_point_minute": "28",
            "sys_point_geo_lat": "-5.0787571",
            "sys_point_geo_long": "-42.8043877",
            "sys_point_status": "Falta",
            "sys_point_reference_code": "a330347242"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "sys_point_id": "84",
            "sys_point_registration": "12345678",
            "sys_point_day": "22",
            "sys_point_month": "12",
            "sys_point_year": "18",
            "sys_point_hour": "02",
            "sys_point_minute": "59",
            "sys_point_geo_lat": "-5.0788858",
            "sys_point_geo_long": "-42.8043689",
            "sys_point_status": "Presença",
            "sys_point_reference_code": "22f1d178ef"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

My interface is this way

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("point/list/")
Call<List<List<Value>>> listPointPeriod(@Field("token") String token,
                                  @Field("registration") String registration,
                                  @Field("from_date") String from_date,
                                  @Field("to_date") String to_date);
```

This is called

```
Call<List<List<Value>>> callPonto = api.listPontoPeriod(token, resultFuncionario.get(i).getOfficials_registration(), dtInicio, dtFim);
callPonto.enqueue(new Callback<List<List<Value>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<List<Value>>> call, Response<List<List<Value>>> response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<List<Ponto>>>(){}.getType();
        List<Ponto> ponto = gson.fromJson(response.body().get(0).toString(), collectionType);   }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<List<Value>>> call, Throwable t) {
       Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Model Ponto

```
public class Ponto {

    String sys_point_id, sys_point_registration, sys_point_day, sys_point_month, sys_point_year, sys_point_hour, sys_point_minute,
        sys_point_geo_lat, sys_point_geo_long, sys_point_status, sys_point_reference_code;

    public Ponto(String sys_point_id, String sys_point_registration, String sys_point_day, String sys_point_month, String sys_point_year, String sys_point_hour, String sys_point_minute, String sys_point_geo_lat, String sys_point_geo_long, String sys_point_status, String sys_point_reference_code) {
        this.sys_point_id = sys_point_id;
        this.sys_point_registration = sys_point_registration;
        this.sys_point_day = sys_point_day;
        this.sys_point_month = sys_point_month;
        this.sys_point_year = sys_point_year;
        this.sys_point_hour = sys_point_hour;
        this.sys_point_minute = sys_point_minute;
        this.sys_point_geo_lat = sys_point_geo_lat;
        this.sys_point_geo_long = sys_point_geo_long;
        this.sys_point_status = sys_point_status;
        this.sys_point_reference_code = sys_point_reference_code;
    }

    public Ponto(){

    }

    public String getSys_point_id() {
        return sys_point_id;
    }

    public String getSys_point_registration() {
        return sys_point_registration;
    }

    public String getSys_point_day() {
        return sys_point_day;
    }

    public String getSys_point_month() {
        return sys_point_month;
    }

    public String getSys_point_year() {
        return sys_point_year;
    }

    public String getSys_point_hour() {
        return sys_point_hour;
    }

    public String getSys_point_minute() {
        return sys_point_minute;
    }

    public String getSys_point_geo_lat() {
        return sys_point_geo_lat;
    }

    public String getSys_point_geo_long() {
        return sys_point_geo_long;
    }

    public String getSys_point_status() {
        return sys_point_status;
    }

    public String getSys_point_reference_code() {
        return sys_point_reference_code;
    }
}
```

my value class

```
public class Value {List<Ponto> point_period_data;public List<Ponto>getPointPeriod() {return point_period_data}}
```

As you saw above my code, I am trying to consume this json, I tried in several ways this was the last one I tried. If someone has already had it and have some answer to solve this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two main issues in the code you provided:

#### 1. The return type of your Retrofit method is wrong

```
Call<List<List<Value>>> listPointPeriod
```

With this, you are expecting a List of List in the Json of your HTTP response. However, the JSON you provided is an object with the "point_period_data" attribute (which is a List of List).

#### 2. You're mixing two methods of parsing the body of your HTTP response

When using Retrofit, the most usual way to parse the body of your response is to use a "converter". In your case, you seem to be using Gson and should have a look to https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson
The official documentation also shows how to add a Converter: https://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration

If you correctly configure Gson with Retrofit, you won't need to manually parse the result in `onResponse`

A corrected version would be something like:

```
public class Value {
    List<List<Ponto>> point_period_data;

    public List<List<Ponto>> getPointPeriodData() {
        return point_period_data;
    }
}
```

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("point/list/")
Call<Value> listPointPeriod(@Field("token") String token,
                                  @Field("registration") String registration,
                                  @Field("from_date") String from_date,
                                  @Field("to_date") String to_date);
```

```
Call<Value> callPonto = api.listPontoPeriod(token, resultFuncionario.get(i).getOfficials_registration(), dtInicio, dtFim);
            callPonto.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                    // Check response.isSuccessful and use response.body
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<List<Value>>> call, Throwable t) {
                   Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your `Value` class is what I called `MyHttpResponse` in my answer. You need to change it to use `List<List<Ponto>>` instead of `List<Ponto>`.
And you need to use `Call<Value>` in all the Retrofit methods (assuming as I said, you configured the Gson converter correctly for your Retrofit instance).

Comment: I edited my answer to show the corrected Value class